# How to limit visibility of a popup menu item only to project which contains a specific file?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

I am looking to limit my popup entry to be only displayed when the project has a specific file 
at its root directory.

I am currently using this code to only have the popup entry shown when a project is clicked on.

```
<visibleWhen
 checkEnabled="false">
 <iterate
        ifEmpty="false"
        operator="or">
     <adapt
           type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
        <test
              property="ProjectSharing.test2">
        </test>
     </adapt>
  </iterate>
</visibleWhen>
```

How can I check for a specific file?

Comment: I think you would have to do this in a property tester that you would have to write. There are some predefined property testers for some things - what file are you looking for?

Comment: aahhh thanks. I didn't know you could make a property tester. The file was a custom one that I make. I made my own property tester and I was able to make it work. thanks :)